# Python data frames - how to select all columns that have a specific substring in their name

Tags: python, dataframe

in Python I have a data frame (df) that contains columns with the following names A_OPEN, A_CLOSE, B_OPEN, B_CLOSE, C_OPEN, C_CLOSE, D_ etc.....

How can I easily select only the columns that contain _CLOSE in their name? A,B,C,D,E,F etc can have any value so I do not want to use the specific column names

In SQL this would be done with the like operator: df[like'%_CLOSE%']

What's the python way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension, *e.g.*:

```
df[[x for x in df.columns if "_CLOSE" in x]]
```

*Example:*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
   columns = ['_CLOSE_A', '_CLOSE_B', 'C'],
   data = [[2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
)
```

Then,

```
>>>print(df[[x for x in df.columns if "_CLOSE" in x]])
   _CLOSE_A  _CLOSE_B
0         2         3
1         3         4
```